# Matrix algebra with notation question on $z_{.2}$

Tags: self-study, matrix, notation

I am doing some matrix calculations and came across an expression which I don't really understand:

$$(z_{i2}-z_{.2})(z_{j2}-z_{.2})$$

As I understand it, those are two integers which are multiplied by each other. My confusion is the dot, what does that mean?

Z is a 2*N matrix.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I suppose its the row mean

Comment: Is it more accurately typed with \bullet, like this: $z_{\bullet 2}?$ If so, then 
@lmaosome is almost certainly correct.